# Define multiple validators for the same field with different updateOn options

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I need to validate a user creation form. I must validate email for 2 scenarios:

1. it's required
2. user can have email from specific domains only (example only from gmail).

For the first scenario, I need to validate for "change", for 2nd scenario for "blur" event. The problem is, I can't validate the same field for different events. At least I don't know how to supposed to do that. I need something like this:

```
this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        email: new FormControl("", {validators: Validators.required, updateOn: "change"}),
        email: new FormControl("", {validators: validateEmail, updateOn: "blur"}),

        ... // more fields
});
```

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: from angular docs, adding [multiple (and possibly custom) validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-reactive-forms)

Comment: Yes, but it's for same event.

Comment: I think that you can "skip" Validators.required, and simulate "manually" this validation as `<div *ngIf="!formBuilder.get('email').value">Required</div>`

Comment: Can you give some scenario, where you need to apply these multiple events in same field?

Comment: I have same issue. I want one validator while typing and one after blur.

Comment: I have the same use case @Nikhil, did you come up with a solution?

Comment: @Monkeeman69 no didn't find any inbuilt solution, I resolved this issue by adding one validation manually on calling a method on (change) and second validation as updateOn: blur